# Creating message queues in local machine

Tags: java, message-queue

How can I create a message queue without using any message queue softwares (like IBM Websphere MQ)? If so, how should I run my java client application in eclipse in my local machine?

Comment: what are you going to connect? Threads, processes, different machines? Are both sides of the connection under your control, or is one side already implemented, requiring specific protocol? Should the queue be persistent, able to survive process crash?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If what you need is to set up a very simple communication between threads, you can use [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) from java.util.concurrent to distribute your message objects.

If the reason why you don't want to use message queue software is just that you don't want anything heavy, then you may consider using [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) - a lightweight messaging library. It is easy to set up and provides simple API known from sockets. I don't know if it is popular in the Java world, but it is used in C++ and Python worlds.